# How Do I include/Import a Custom Widget from the Parent theme into My Child Theme?

Tags: functions, widgets

I'm trying to make a small modification to a custom widget that was included with a clients parent theme.

Whenever I remove the parents version of the widget (for testing purposes) the child version of the widget does not take over. Instead, the widget simply disappears.

I've mimicked the directory structure of the parent theme, copied my modified widget .php file into the proper location, and have included the following code in my child themes function.php:

```
include("../maxmag-child/widgets/widget-tabs.php");
```

Any idea why the child's version of the widget isn't available?

Comment: Show us how you have written the "child widget". Did you extend the parent class?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "extend the parent class". 

The only edit I did to the widget was remove a div and it's contents.

Comment: So you copy pasted the files contents, changed it slightly, uploaded it into a child theme sub folder and included it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Then the same class is loaded twice. It's the same as defining a function twice: It doesn't work.

Comment: I tried to remove the include from the parents function.php but it still didn't work. Would there be something else I would have to adjust?

Comment: Read my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Either go and [`extend`](http://php.net/manual/de/keyword.extends.php) the class, or copy, paste and rename it (not recommended).

```
class Child_Theme_Widget extends Parent_Theme_Widget
{
    // just re-define/override the parent theme widgets methods (functions) here
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: @user32576 You'll have to read the link to PHP.net and you need to learn some PHP (or get someone who does this for you).

Comment: Okay, I'll take a look and see if I can piece it together.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used your suggestion to find a solution.

Here's what I did:  
Registered a new widget  
`function maxmag_tabs_load_widgets() {  

 register_widget( 'maxmag_tabs_widget' );  
 register_widget( 'maxmag_tabs_child_widget');  

}`  

Use the extend function on my new widget  

`class maxmag_tabs_child_widget extends maxmag_tabs_widget {
}`

Comment: Sorry about the formatting above, the double space at the end of my lines did not create linebreaks. What's up with that?

Comment: @JoshuaG Great that you found a solution! Hint: You can now tick the answer as solution (below the voting arrows on the left side of the question) and even edit the answer to reflect your solution (community edits are appreciated). Comments don't take line breaks - that's what questions and answers are for.